# Proration in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table of locations and their allocations in integers. As the overall allocations increase, the underlying distribution needs to increase in proportion, while setting off any rounding errors.

[image]

What I have tried is:

```
new_distribution=new_alloc-ROUND(NVL(SUM(original distribution) OVER (PARTITION BY location rows between unbounded preceding and 1 PRECEDING),0)*(new_alloc/original alloc),0) as num
```

However, the totals don't match to 40. How do I achieve this in SQL/Redshift/Oracle such that new distribution is close to original while totalling to 40?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by assigning values by *truncating* and then distributing what is left over to some of the rows.  This looks like:

```
select t.*,
       (trunc_new_dist + (case when seqnum <= new_alloc - total_trunc_new_dist then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as new_dist
from (select t.*,
             trunc(new_alloc * orig_dist) / orig_alloc as trunc_new_dist,
             sum( trunc(new_alloc * orig_dist) / orig_alloc ) over () as total_trunc_new_dist,
             row_number() over (order by location) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Works like a charm! 



There is a typo in brackets. Appending corrected query below for others:
SELECT t2.*,
       ( trunc_new_dist + ( CASE WHEN seqnum <= new_alloc - total_trunc_new_dist THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ) AS new_dist
FROM   (SELECT t.*,
               Trunc(new_alloc * orig_dist / orig_alloc) AS trunc_new_dist,
               Sum(Trunc(new_alloc * orig_dist / orig_alloc)) OVER () AS total_trunc_new_dist,
               Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY location) AS seqnum
        FROM  t) t2